# Declare random list with list name as argument command

Tags: lists

I have two list of questions. I want to create a command for declare random list with list name as argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\qfirstlist{%
{I - 1?}%
{I - 2?}%
{I - 3?}%
{I - 4?}%
{I - 5?}%
{I - 6?}%
{I - 7?}%
{I - 8?}%
{I - 9?}%
{I - 10?}%
}

\def\qsecondlist{%
{II - 1?}%
{II - 2?}%
{II - 3?}%
{II - 4?}%
{II - 5?}%
{II - 6?}%
{II - 7?}%
{II - 8?}%
{II - 9?}%
{II - 10?}%
}

\newcommand\declarelist[1]{
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{#1}{\csname q#1\endcsname}
}

\declarelist{firstlist}
\declarelist{secondlist}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{firstlist}
\z

\pgfmathrandomitem\z{secondlist} 
\z
\end{document}
```

I expect that `\declarelist{xxx}` will work as `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{xxx}{\qxxx}` but it's don't. After `\declarelist{firstlist}` it's no list of items, there are list of one item `I - 1?I - 2?I - 3?I - 4?I - 5?I - 6?I - 7?I - 8?I - 9?I - 10?`

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  `\declarelist{firstlist}\qfirstlist` produces the same output as `\pgfmathrandomitem\z{firstlist}\z`.

Comment: I want refuse to use `\qfirstlist` token. I need operate with one identefire `firstlist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `\declarelist` as

```
\newcommand\declarelist[1]%
  {\expandafter\let\expandafter\tmp\csname q#1\endcsname
   \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{#1}{\tmp}%
  }
```

then it will work.

The point is that `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist` expands its first argument *once* before processing it. With your definition, expanding `\csname q#1\endcsname` for `#1` = `firstlist` will result in `\qfirstlist`, which will be interpreted as a list with a single element. Randomly selecting an element will always result in `\qfirstlist`, which later is expanded to the complete list. With the definition above, however, the expansion of `\tmp` yields `{I - 1?}{I - 2?}{I - 3?}...` as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\qfirstlist{%
{I - 1?}%
{I - 2?}%
{I - 3?}%
{I - 4?}%
{I - 5?}%
{I - 6?}%
{I - 7?}%
{I - 8?}%
{I - 9?}%
{I - 10?}%
}

\def\qsecondlist{%
{II - 1?}%
{II - 2?}%
{II - 3?}%
{II - 4?}%
{II - 5?}%
{II - 6?}%
{II - 7?}%
{II - 8?}%
{II - 9?}%
{II - 10?}%
}

\newcommand\declarelist[1]%
  {\expandafter\let\expandafter\tmp\csname q#1\endcsname
   \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{#1}{\tmp}%
  }

\declarelist{firstlist}
\declarelist{secondlist}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{firstlist}
\z

\pgfmathrandomitem\z{secondlist} 
\z
\end{document}
```